# Create array from mysqli

Tags: php

MySQL table (allow_ip)

```
username |      ip
  @@@    |192.215.154.251
         |
         |
         |
```

I want to take the all the ip and create array but dont work!

```
$rs=$mysqli->query('SELECT ip FROM allow_ip');
$i=0;
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc())
{
    $allow[$i]=$row['ip'];
    $i++;
}
```

I want this: $allow = array("ip[0]", "ip[1]",....,"ip[x]");

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you mean?

```
$arrDbEntry = $mysqli->query("SELECT ip FROM allow_ip");

$arrAllow = array();

while($intRow = $arrDbEntry->fetch_assoc()) {
    $arrAllow[] = $arrDbEntry['ip'];
}

// print_r($arrAllow);
```

Although, I think if you increment `$i` each time in your loop, that should do the trick.  You could also create a small function, call it something like `selectAndFetchAll($strDbQuery, $arrParameters)` and make it return an array of results.

Answer (score 0):

before the `while` loop, declare $allow as array: `$allow = array();`
and inside the loop, increese $i: `$i++;`

Comment: Ok work, but now i have other problem!
I have login system and i do this:

$rs=$mysqli->query('SELECT ip FROM allow_ip');
$allow = array();
$i=0;
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc())
{
    $allow[$i]=$row['ip'];
    $i++;
}
if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allow) && !in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"], $allow))
{
header("Location: ../../404.php");
exit();
}
Work but.....
Dont work logout!

Comment: please consider opening a new question for this

Comment: you need to call `session_start();` and `session_destroy();` inside your if condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function selectInfo($columnName,$table){
      include('../includes/db_connect.php'); 
      $select = "SELECT $columnName FROM $table";
      $selected = $db->query($select);
      while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($selected)){
      print_r(array_keys($rows));
      }
  }
```

Then, just build it into your class - if your using one...

```
    $showInfo = new dbFunction();
    $showInfo->selectInfo('Column Name','Your Table');
```

or just the function...

```
    selectInfo('Column Name','Your Table');
```